# Printing user specified column from JTable

Tags: java, printing, jtable

I have an application, and I would like to print a JTable, but since it has many columns, I would like user to select/limit which columns to print so it can fit in regular printer paper.

I'm using JTable.print() function to print. (http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/misc/printtable.html)
Right now, my solution, is to create another JTable with the columns that user selected, then repopulate the table with the data, then send it to printer.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: The benefit of doing it your way is that the user sees exactly what is going to be printed, just like a print preview.

Answer (score 0):

As I've answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003159/how-to-print-out-specific-rows-columns-of-a-jtable/20783282), I solved it by hiding columns before printing and restoring columns after printing:

```
// get column num from settings
int num = gridSettings.getColumnsOnPage();// first <num> columns of the table will be printed   

final TableColumnModel model = table.getColumnModel();

// list of removed columns. After printing we add them back
final List<TableColumn> removed = new ArrayList<TableColumn>();

int columnCount = model.getColumnCount();

// hiding columns which are not used for printing
for(int i = num; i < columnCount; ++i){
    TableColumn col = model.getColumn(num);
    removed.add(col);
    model.removeColumn(col);
}                                                   

// printing after GUI will be updated
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // table printing
        try {
            table.print(PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, null, null, true, hpset, true); // here can be your printing
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // columns restoring
        for(TableColumn col : removed){
            model.addColumn(col);
        }
    }
});
```

For printing specific part of a JTable, just change a little bit this code.

Answer (score 0):

The best way: just set column width to zero then it will be hidden:)

```
TableColumn column = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);

//backup first
int minWidth=column.getMinWidth();
int width=column.getPreferredWidth();

//to hide:
column.setMinWidth(0);
column.setPreferredWidth(0);

//to show it back:
column.setMinWidth(minWidth);
column.setPreferredWidth(width);
```