# How to print out specific rows/columns of a JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, awt

I am able to print a full JTable, but actually I would like more to print just a specific part of a JTable, for example from Row 10 to Row 50 and Column 70 to Column 150.
How to do it ?

Comment: Possibly using a [`TableRowSorter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableRowSorter.html) (which also performs filtering) to limit the rows to those in the range.

Comment: Does this limit the number of rows in the view without modifying the model ?

Comment: A `TableRowSorter` works only on the view side. It does not affect the underlying `TableModel`

Comment: Is there anything like this for the columns ?

Comment: `JTable#removeColumn`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get cell bounds for the selected fragment and calculate desired region (`Rectangle`), define clip region to paint only desired region, in the printable use `Graphics's` translate() method to shift the rendering.

Comment: That's approximately what I did. Using Rectangle solved a big part of the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this problem too. Solved by hiding columns before printing and restoring columns after printing:

```
// get column num from settings
int num = gridSettings.getColumnsOnPage();// first <num> columns of the table will be printed   

final TableColumnModel model = table.getColumnModel();

// list of removed columns. After printing we add them back
final List<TableColumn> removed = new ArrayList<TableColumn>();

int columnCount = model.getColumnCount();

// hiding columns which are not used for printing
for(int i = num; i < columnCount; ++i){
    TableColumn col = model.getColumn(num);
    removed.add(col);
    model.removeColumn(col);
}                                                   

// printing after GUI will be updated
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // table printing
        try {
            table.print(PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH, null, null, true, hpset, true); // here can be your printing
        } catch (PrinterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // columns restoring
        for(TableColumn col : removed){
            model.addColumn(col);
        }
    }
});
```

For printing your specific part of a JTable, just change a little bit this code.

Comment: The best way is just set the column width to zero then it will be hidden:). I've answered here >> https://stackoverflow.com/a/67255138/7420535