# Printing selected rows from JTable

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

I'm making a java swing application, I'm also a newbie programer (1 and a half years programing).

I'm trying to code inside a button a way to print (in a printer, not in console) the preselected rows (by a user) of a jTable, which has been printed (in the window) by a Query before.

This is my code (inside the button), I know it's worng. I thought , the way to do this was copying in a temp jTable all the selected rows, and then print the temp jTable, but i can't achieve this.

```
    MessageFormat header = new MessageFormat("- {TABLE} -"); 
        try {
            DefaultTableModel viewModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
            DefaultTableModel printModel = new DefaultTableModel(viewModel.getRowCount(), viewModel.getColumnCount());
            JTable toPrint = new JTable(printModel);

            int[] selectedRows = jTable.getSelectedRows(); 
            for (int r=0;r<selectedRows.length;r++){
                toPrint.addRowSelectionInterval(r, r);
            }


            toPrint.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH,header,null);

        } catch (java.awt.print.PrinterException e1) {
             System.err.format("Cannot print %s%n", e1.getMessage()); 
        }
```

To sum up, I just want to print (in a printer) the selected rows of an existing jTable.

I also tryed this -> ([how to print selected rows JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580954/how-to-print-selected-rows-jtable)) and other possible solutions, but I can't make them work for me.

Answer (score 3):

You kind of missed the "real important" "trickery" part...

```
JTable toPrint = new JTable(printModel);
toPrint.setSize(toPrint.getPreferredSize());
JTableHeader tableHeader = toPrint.getTableHeader();
tableHeader.setSize(tableHeader.getPreferredSize());
toPrint.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH);
```

It's really, really important that you set the size of the table and header

**Updated**

If you had basically copied the code from [how to print selected rows JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580954/how-to-print-selected-rows-jtable) it would have basically worked

Change...

```
DefaultTableModel viewModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
DefaultTableModel printModel = new DefaultTableModel(viewModel.getRowCount(), viewModel.getColumnCount());
JTable toPrint = new JTable(printModel);

int[] selectedRows = jTable.getSelectedRows(); 
for (int r=0;r<selectedRows.length;r++){
    toPrint.addRowSelectionInterval(r, r);
}
```

to

```
DefaultTableModel viewModel = (DefaultTableModel) jTable.getModel();
DefaultTableModel printModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, viewModel.getColumnCount());
JTable toPrint = new JTable(printModel);

for (int row : table.getSelectedRows()) {
    printModel.addRow((Vector)viewModel.getDataVector().get(row));
}
```

> It prints the exact number of selected rows, but without the data. –

So, I basically went back to [how to print selected rows JTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580954/how-to-print-selected-rows-jtable), updated it to fix the "minor" bug so it would only print the selected rows, and run it without an issue...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.JTableHeader;

public class TestPrint {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPrint();
    }

    public TestPrint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 26);
                for (int row = 0; row < 26; row++) {
                    Vector data = new Vector(26);
                    for (int col = 0; col < 26; col++) {

                        String value = row + "x" + ((char) (col + 'A'));
                        data.add(value);

                    }
                    model.addRow(data);
                }

                JTable table = new JTable(model);

                JButton print = new JButton("Print");
                print.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        try {
                            DefaultTableModel viewModel = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
                            DefaultTableModel printModel = new DefaultTableModel(0, viewModel.getColumnCount());
                            for (int row : table.getSelectedRows()) {
                                printModel.addRow((Vector) viewModel.getDataVector().get(row));
                            }
                            JTable toPrint = new JTable(printModel);
                            toPrint.setSize(toPrint.getPreferredSize());
                            JTableHeader tableHeader = toPrint.getTableHeader();
                            tableHeader.setSize(tableHeader.getPreferredSize());
                            toPrint.print(JTable.PrintMode.FIT_WIDTH);
                        } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                            ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new JScrollPane(table));
                frame.add(print, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

What I would recommend is that you start testing your code and make sure that the table is actually adding the rows you expect to the `printModel`

Comment: Looks like nothing is selected (I updated the second piece, seems there might have been a bug :P)

Comment: Using this line -> printModel.addRow(viewModel.getDataVector().get(row));
 It says that it needs to be a Vector and asks me to set it like this -> printModel.addRow((Vector) viewModel.getDataVector().get(row)); nothing changes.

Comment: I'm assuming you have rows selected :P

Comment: (https://gyazo.com/0674e4929ceb6ecd8de13fe18797c7ef) Blue lines are the selected ones, thats what it prints -> (https://gyazo.com/5d468181d7c47f8882781ea6ffea63d0)

Comment: It prints the exact number of selected rows, but without the data.

Comment: Since I have no context your data or how it's represented, I can only provide you with demonstratable and working examples.  I went back to my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580954/how-to-print-selected-rows-jtable), updated it to only include the selected rows and it works just fine for me