# JTable print method not using entire page width

Tags: java, swing, printing, jtable

When I try to print my `JTable`, it automatically shrinks it down horizontally. How can I make it use the entire page width? I already tried both `PrintMode.Normal` and `PrintMode.Fit_Width`. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I found a temporary fix for it. I display the JTable before i print it, so if i resize it and then try to print, it is scaled down and fits on my printed page.

Comment: Take a close look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26580954/how-to-print-selected-rows-jtable/26581137#26581137) and [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34742195/printing-selected-rows-from-jtable/34742430#34742430)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.